# Error when generating multiple PDF files from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I created an Excel file with VBA code in Excel 2010, 32 bit.

I have an Excel file with ~20 sheets. The sheets are generated from 1 template sheet.

I created a form where i can select the sheets to print to PDF. When i select > 10, Excel crashes with error "Cannot complete task with available resources". Also making a smaller selection doesn't fix the problem. First time it works, but then making the next selection of 4 it crashes.

The sheets are 1 A4 in printsize and contain 30 active-x components (text and selection fields)

I use the standard Excel 2010 code to save to PDF. Here is a part of the code.

```
Public Sub PrintToPDF()
'print every selected item
For intItem = 0 To frmPrint.lstReports.ListCount - 1

  If frmPrint.lstReports.Selected(intItem) Then

     Sheets(shtReport).ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strLocatie & Sheets(shtReport).Name & " " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), OpenAfterPublish:=False

  End If

Next
End Sub
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Can i free up memory?

Many thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: Have you tried to assign Sheets(shtReport) to Worksheet variable and assign the variable to Nothing after the export? Maybe that way you could close the file handler and free memory used.

Comment: when i delete all active-x components, the proces works fine. Replacing the assignment to worksheet and set = nothing helped a lot.  I'm replacing the active-x components now, just to be sure it also works on slower workstations. Thanx for the suggestion!